# Post UI Tabs plugin double fade effect

Tags: posts, tabs, user-interface

After clicking a tab (any tab), the fade in effect occurs twice. Curious how to only have this occur only once. I disabled every plugin to ensure that this was not a JS conflict elsewhere and it appears to be isolated to this plugin:

http://www.ernestsports.com/products/ernest-sports-es12-golf-improvement/

Great plugin. Works like a champ!

Thanks in advance ~

Comment: Javascript Q. Belongs to SO.

Comment: This should be on **wordpress.org** really, i do offer support for my plugins, but i don't typically do it here, it's not really a good fit for this site. Please use [this link](http://wordpress.org/tags/put#postform) to post a topic on **wordpress.org** and i'll be happy to try and help you isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this anyway because i've already narrowed down the source of your problem and it's not a Javascript one.

I have AdblockPlus installed in Firefox so i went through your scripts blocking them in chunks at a time until i was down to just the PUT scripts, and the problem was still present, so it was evident the issue was and is not with Javascript.

The only other thing i could think of that could manipulate an element beyond JS is a stylesheet, so i then went about blocking stylesheets one at a time and narrowed it down to being something inside the main stylesheet for the theme, ie. this one.

http://www.ernestsports.com/wp-content/themes/toolbox/style.css

I don't know specifically which style or styles in there are causing the issue, but my suggestion would be to go through the stylesheet and delete chunks of CSS at a time, then refresh the page to see if the problem is still there, if it is, keep deleting more chunks until you find the area of CSS that causes the problem.

You only need delete CSS temporarily, just to narrow down specifically which area of theme's styling is at fault, but blocking that stylesheet did get rid of the double fade(which tells me it's definately that file causing the problem)

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: You were right. I almost pulled my hair out trying to diagnose this, however, I finally narrowed it down. In my custom CSS, I specified in the class .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {: display: block} which was conflicting with other display properties. Primarily the style puling from Google's jquery.uitabs.css:

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    display: none !important;
}

Many, many, many thanks again!!

Comment: Happy to help.. :)